# How can I create a truly complicated collection?

Tags: collections, dictionary

Looks like I will never run out of problems. Now I would like to initialize a Dictionary like this( exactly this):

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>> origRes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>
```

Or else I need a collection, which can contains one string and two integer values. And will enough a simple `for` or `foreach` loop to collect all these datas( the string can be a key value)?

**Update**

```
public static Dictionary<int, int> resRequest(string requestedForm)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> kp = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, int>> origRes = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
            origRes.Add("Polübiosz", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(560,310));
            origRes.Add("Morze", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(690, 510));
            origRes.Add("Caesar", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(700, 500));
            origRes.Add("OwnCrypt", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(830, 570));
            origRes.Add("Hamming", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(850, 500));
            origRes.Add("Kezdőkép", new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1280, 1024));

            foreach(KeyValuePair<string,KeyValuePair<int, int>> pair in origRes)
            {
                if(pair.Key==requestedForm)
                {
                    kp.Add(pair.Value.Key,pair.Value.Value);
                }
            }
            return kp;
        }
```

Here is my full method And I want to get the key and the value from the `KeyValuePair`, but the returned Dictionary doesn't contains it or I don't know, but on the calling side there is no key or value attribute only keys and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a class that contains a string, int, int and populate a simpler dictionary with that?

So instead of

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, int>>
```

Do:

```
Dictionary<string, MyType>
```

Where MyType is something like:

```
class MyType {
    public string KeyVal { get; set; } // optional - to match your dict key
    public int Int1Val{ get; set; }
    public int Int2Val{ get; set; }
}
```